# Importing Twitter user follower count into Google Spreadsheet using importXML

Tags: xml, twitter, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a column of Twitter user handles (without the "@"). I'm trying to get a follower count using the following formula:

```
=importXML("http://twitter.com/"&A1,"//a[@data-nav='followers']")
```

where the user handle is in column A, but the spreadsheet returns

```
Error: Imported Xml content can not be parsed.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I continue to do a lot of work on this, and made a full Google Sheet you can copy and deconstruct [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rDXUPkZBMqvYmof8rhG4maei4NfPlvyHNYvfVP6ovSs/edit?usp=sharing).

If you look at the importXML tab, you will see that I prefer to pull the full Profile Stats in one call, and then parse it out as you see fit elsewhere in the spreadsheet. Here is an example:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(importxml("https://twitter.com/"&A1,"//span[@class='ProfileNav-value']")),5,1)
```

I have pulled the direct follower counts before, but if you want other stats anyway, then it can make the sheet heavy, and it used to be limited to 50 or 100 requests per sheet, so getting an array worked out better.

Let me know if that works, or if you need just followers and I could revisit that.